# Error installing Visual Studio 15 Preview 4 - Windows 7 SP1 requires KB2952664

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

As per the latest announcement from Microsoft [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudio/2016/08/22/visual-studio-15-preview-4/) I'm trying to install Visual Studio 15 Preview 4 on my machine. My machine is Windows Server 2008 R2 Enterprise edition. I had already installed Visual Studio 15 Preview 3 but now I want to install Preview 4. The moment I try to run the installer "vs_bootstrapper.exe" downloadable from above mentioned URL it fails with following error.

> Windows 7 SP1 requires KB2952664.

It shows the above message in a message box without any other redirection to some error log file or retry option.

[image]

I also tried running the installer exe with administrative privileges as well but to no success. I'm stuck. Can anyone help me if you also have faced or fixed this issue?

**Note**: I'm on a hyper-v box.

Comment: Preview 3 was less horrible but equally useless. I could install it but couldn't run a simple `hello world` console application - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38629093/msb4018-the-getframeworkpath-task-failed-unexpectedly

Comment: asked them to fix their stuff. https://twitter.com/zproxy/status/769139119582838784

Comment: Have you uninstalled Preview 3?

Comment: @qxg Yep.  I tried that route as well after facing this issue. Uninstalled preview 3, rebooted my box and then retried but it still gives the very same error.

Comment: Is your windows server up to date? Installing latest windows update may help.

Comment: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/371/cant-install-preview-4-with-error-windows-7-sp1-re.html?inRegister=true

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Visual Studio community link from Daniel A. White helped me resolve this issue. The problem is faced by many users and you can find the details [here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/371/cant-install-preview-4-with-error-windows-7-sp1-re.html).
Quoting from the thread:

> It seems that installer is looking for a file named "dismapi.dll".
>   This file has to be present in either %windir%\system32 or
>   %windir%\SysWow64 or any subdirectory.
>
> A (dirty) workaroud is to create an empty file named dismapi.dll in
>   any of those directories and then you can install Preview 4... :)

As suggested in the problem thread, creating a dummy `dismapi.dll` file in `%windir%\SysWow64` path helped me get past this issue. After creating the dummy file, the welcome page of the installer finally popped-up. The first solution to create the dummy file in `%windir%\system32` didn't work for me. The two alternative solutions could be OS dependent. Mine was Windows Server 2008 R2.

Comment: now i get: Package 'Microsoft.DiagnosticsHub.KB2882822.Win7' failed to install
Package 'Microsoft.Net.3.5.KB2664825.Win7.x64' failed to install
Package 'Microsoft.Net.3.5.KB2664825.Win7.x86' failed to install
2016-08-27T13:19:42 : Error : Failed to install product.

Comment: Worked like a charm - after I installed the KB itself and restarted.
Note: Make sure .NET 4.6 and targeting pack is installed as well.

Comment: seems it needs to log in to get a trial license. asks to connect to https://secure.aadcdn.microsoftonline-p.com and https://account.live.com and https://cs.microsoft.com

Comment: I installed the Windows 10 ADK version 1607 then copied the correct DISMAPI.DLL from (not a dummy) from "C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Assessment and Deployment Kit\Deployment Tools\x86\DISM\" to "C:\Windows\SysWOW64\" then it started.

Comment: Does it require installing KB2952664, and/or enabling Windows Updates? I am not willing to enable WU, as it may pull Windows 10

Comment: @Ajay I didn't try that route once it got fixed by placing the dummy file. Would suggest you using Code Chief's advice if you are worried about Windows 10 hijacking your machine.

Comment: This workaround worked on Win7 x64 with latest updates.